# Find two largest numbers in input

Tags: c, numbers, max

I need to make a program that will perform the following task:

> Enter N natural numbers. Complete the input with 0. Output the number
> of the maximal number.

I have already done this, and you can see the code below:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int i = 0, num, max_place = -1;
int max = -2147483647;

printf("Start enter numbers, bruh (please end input with 0):\n");

scanf("%d", &num);
while (num != 0) {
    if (num >= max) {
        max = num;
        max_place = i;
    }
    i++;
    scanf("%d", &num);
}

if (max_place == -1) printf("Numbers were not entered");
else printf("\nMax number was on %d place, bruh", max_place + 1);

return 0;
}
```

The teacher then made the task more difficult – the program needs to print the maximum number and the next maximum after it of the entered numbers.

How can I do it?

Comment: Keep a variable that will hold the *previously* found maximum. BTW, the "if (num==0` check is redundant, as your `while` condition is already covering it.

Comment: Do you mean like the 2 highest numbers?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy yes. sorry, eng is not my native lang, sometimes it is hard to communicate on it)

Comment: You removed the `while` rather than `if`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. oops, my bad :D

Comment: Note: code fails when `N==1` and `num == -2147483648`.  Instead of `-2147483647`, consider `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use arrays and sort use that way. if not, this is in your code

```
int main(void) {
    int i = 0, num, max_place = -1, second_max_place = -1;
    int max = -2147483647;
    int second_max = -2147483647;
 
    printf("Start enter numbers, bruh (please end input with 0):\n");
 
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while (num != 0) {
        if (num == 0) break;
        if (num >= max) {
            second_max = max;
            second_max_place = max_place;
            max = num;
            max_place = i;
        }
        if(num < max && num >= second_max){
            second_max = num;
            second_max_place = i;
        }
        
        i++;
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
 
    if (max_place == -1) printf("Numbers were not entered");
    else{
        printf("\nMax number was on %d place, bruh", max_place + 1);
        printf("\nSecond Max number was on %d place, bruh", second_max_place + 1);
    } 
 
    return 0;
}
```